# Same Debug, Different Console Result

Tags: c#, dictionary, unity-game-engine, save

Lately I have been learning how to save dictionaries in Unity. It appears to be working correctly; however there is something I am curious about. In the code that follows I have Debug.Log() lines that show the same lists in two different formats; for lack of a better term.

```
public class ButtonMethods : MonoBehaviour
{
SerializableDictionaryToList DictionaryToList;

string DictionarySavePath = "";

private void Start()
{
    DictionaryToList = new SerializableDictionaryToList();
    //DictionaryToList.Add("Play Hard?", false);
    //DictionaryToList.Add("Work Hard?", true);
    //Debug.Log(DictionaryToList["Work Hard?"]);

    DictionarySavePath = Application.persistentDataPath + Path.AltDirectorySeparatorChar + "SaveDictionary.json";
}

// Connected to Create List button
// invokes OnBeforeSerialize() method from Dictionary
public void CreateList()
{ 
    DictionaryToList.OnBeforeSerialize();
    for(int i = 0; i < DictionaryToList.Values.Count; i++)
    { Debug.Log($"{DictionaryToList.Keys[i]} | Key List Element {i} from CreateList()"); }

    for(int i = 0; i < DictionaryToList.Keys.Count; i++)
    { Debug.Log($"{DictionaryToList.Values[i]} | Value List Element {i} from CreateList()"); }
}

public void CreateDictionary()
{ DictionaryToList.OnAfterDeserialize(); }

public void ClearDictionary()
{
    Debug.Log("Clear Dictionary");
    DictionaryToList.Clear();
}

// Saves the separate lists to JSON files for use between sessions
// Connected to button Save Dictionary
public void SaveLists()
{
    string SaveDictionary = JsonUtility.ToJson(DictionaryToList);

    File.WriteAllText(DictionarySavePath, SaveDictionary);
    Debug.Log($"{SaveDictionary} | Saved Dictionary from SaveLists()");

    DictionaryToList.Keys.Add("After Save");
    DictionaryToList.Values.Add(true);

    for(int i = 0; i < DictionaryToList.Keys.Count; i++)
    { Debug.Log($"{DictionaryToList.Keys[i]} | Element {i} of Keys List from SaveLists()"); }

    for(int i = 0; i < DictionaryToList.Values.Count; i++)
    { Debug.Log($"{DictionaryToList.Values[i]} | Element {i} of Values List from SaveLists()"); }
}

// Loads the separate lists and replaces them in the Dictionary class for use with OnAfterDeserialize method
// Connected to button Load Lists
public void LoadListsJSON()
{
    Debug.Log("Load Lists...");

    var inputKeyString = File.ReadAllText(DictionarySavePath);
    JsonUtility.FromJsonOverwrite(inputKeyString, DictionaryToList);

72   for(int i = 0; i < DictionaryToList.Keys.Count; i++)
    { Debug.Log($"{DictionaryToList.Keys} | Element {i} of Keys List from LoadLists()"); }

    for(int i = 0; i < DictionaryToList.Values.Count; i++)
76   { Debug.Log($"{DictionaryToList.Values} | Element {i} of Values List from LoadLists()"); }

    Debug.Log("...Lists Loaded");
}
}
```

Lines 72 to 76, these are Debug lines in LoadListsJSON() method, display in the console as follows:

```
System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] | Element 1 of Keys List from LoadLists()
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.String] | Element 0 of Keys List from LoadLists()
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Boolean] | Element 0 of Values List from LoadLists()
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)

System.Collections.Generic.List`1[System.Boolean] | Element 1 of Values List from LoadLists()
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
```

The class this is interacting with is:

```
[Serializable]
public class SerializableDictionaryToList : Dictionary<string, bool>, ISerializationCallbackReceiver

{
[SerializeField]
public List<string> Keys = new List<string>();

[SerializeField]
public List<bool> Values = new List<bool>();

//Takes key, value pair and splits into respective lists
public void OnBeforeSerialize()
{
    Keys.Clear();
    Values.Clear();

    foreach(KeyValuePair<string, bool> pair in this)
    {
        Keys.Add(pair.Key);
        Values.Add(pair.Value);
    }
}

public void OnAfterDeserialize()
{
    this.Clear();

    for(int i = 0; i < Keys.Count; i++)
    {
        this.Add(Keys[i], Values[i]);
        Debug.Log($"{Keys[i]} | {Values[i]} Dictionary from OnAfterDeserialize()");
    }
}
}
```

The debug lines for the same variable appear as such:

```
Play Hard? | False Dictionary from OnAfterDeserialize()
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)

Work Hard? | True Dictionary from OnAfterDeserialize()
UnityEngine.Debug:Log (object)
```

I was curious as to why this is. The above are after the lists have been added back to the Dictionary from a save file. Is it because the Json file saved the dictionary object and not the lists or is there something else I'm unaware of?

The code seems to be working as desired, but I would love an answer for this if possible. Thanks!

Comment: So your question is about the difference between `{DictionaryToList.Keys}` vs `{DictionaryToList.Keys[i]}`?

Comment: It is about how the console outputs the same list differently. One displays correctly, from the SerializableDictionaryToList while the other, from ButtonMethods, displays as if it doesn't know what is in the list.

Is that because one uses the individual elements as opposed to the entire list?

Comment: I mean you should have a closer look at `LoadListsJSON` because the logging is different. But I have no idea why you would create `SerializableDictionaryToList` as a dictionary, with extra properties for keys and values. Particularly since `Dictionary` already has properties with those names. Are you ignoring compiler warnings?